# Deleting model inside for loop causes faulty incrementing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing this in my controller:

```
    $latestRevision = \DB::table('revisions')->latest('created_at')->first();
    $firstRevision = \DB::table('revisions')->find($id);
    $revisions = \DB::table('revisions')->whereBetween('created_at', [$firstRevision->created_at, $latestRevision->created_at])->get();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($revisions); $i++) { 
        Property::find($revisions[$i]->revisionable_id)->update([$revisions[$i]->key => $revisions[$i]->old_value]);
        \DB::table('revisions')->whereId($revisions[$i]->id)->delete();
    }
```

Which causes Laravel to generate hundreds of new tables, is this because i am deleting a model which is also called in the for loop as parameter?

How can i delete those tables one time and not over and over? But just the count(10) amount

Example:

I start with 30 revisions but this foreach returns 187:

```
        $latestRevision = \DB::table('revisions')->latest('created_at')->first();
        $firstRevision = \DB::table('revisions')->find($id);
        $revisions = \DB::table('revisions')->whereBetween('created_at', [$firstRevision->created_at, $latestRevision->created_at])->get();
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($revisions as $key => $value) {
            array_push($arr, $value);
        }
```

Comment: did you mean , that you only delete that revision between given date

Comment: Yes it should be a foreach loop sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use limit(). This method will return only the first x rows of your query. Try this:

```
 $revisions = \DB::table('revisions')->whereBetween('created_at', [$firstRevision->created_at, $latestRevision->created_at])->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! But the count was just an example from me to make clear that i only want the models inside the foreach loop to be deleted once and not repeatedly